# $watcher на Service Angular

Tags: angularjs

Хочу делать так чтоб обновления **Сервиса** изменились в **контролере**, без $broadcast.
Попробовал делать так, но результатa 0

```
//Controller 1
$scope.tpl = MyService.getTemplate();
$scope.$watch($scope.tpl, function(oldValue, newValue){
    $scope.tpl = newValue;
});

//Controller 2
MyService.setTemplate('template1');

//Service
var template = 'template';

var setTempale = function(tpl)
{
  tempalate = tpl;
}

var getTempale = function()
{
  return template;
}
```

в сервисе наверняка изменяется но в *Controller 1* остается прежнее значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
 $scope.$watch(
        function() {
            return MyService.getTemplate();
        }, function(oldValue, newValue) {
            $scope.tpl = newValue;
        }
    );
```

Первый аргумент функции `$watch` должен быть либо строкой, по которой будет определено имя наблюдаемого свойства в `$scope`, либо функция, которая будет возвращать наблюдаемое значение при каждом dirty check. В вашем случае как раз нужно сделать функцию.